# TKCalendar - Custom image for day?

Tags: ios, calendar, uiimage

I'm using the standard implementation of the TKCalendar for iOS and because there isn't much documentation on it I was wondering if anyone knows of a simply way of setting a custom image for a day of the month.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's all of your answers are wrong. What I wanted was the ability to change each day's image to a custom image that I would choose for every day. 
I hacked the code together and got it to work . If anyone is looking for how to do this, just got go to TKCalendarMonthView.m and find the

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

method. Now in this method, copy in the following (this is a simplified version of the code that I have so you have to build it up yourself):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage *tile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile.png")];

CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 44);
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, r, tile.CGImage);



int index = 0;

UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:dateFontSize];
UIFont *font2 =[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:dotFontSize];
UIColor *color = [UIColor grayColor];

    //first do the boxes that are still visible from the previous month 
    //
    //

if(firstOfPrev>0){
    [color set];
    for(int i = firstOfPrev;i<= lastOfPrev;i++){
        r = [self rectForCellAtIndex:index];

    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////

    int indexMoved = 7;
    r.origin.y -= indexMoved; //this moves the block to put it back in it's place

    //add an image to the rect - note you can add them over each other 
    [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"t.png"]] drawInRect:r];


    r.origin.y += indexMoved; //move back the block


    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////


        if ([marks count] > 0)
            [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:[[marks objectAtIndex:index] boolValue] font:font font2:font2];
        else
            [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:NO font:font font2:font2];
        index++;

    }
}


    //Now to blocks for current month 
    //
    //
color = [UIColor colorWithRed:59/255. green:73/255. blue:88/255. alpha:1];
[color set];

for(int i=1; i <= daysInMonth; i++){
    r = [self rectForCellAtIndex:index];

     ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////

    int indexMoved = 7;
    r.origin.y -= indexMoved; //this moves the block to put it back in it's place

    //add an image to the rect - note you can add them over each other 
    [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"t.png"]] drawInRect:r];


    r.origin.y += indexMoved; //move back the block


    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////

    if(today == i){ //this is done to highlight today's block
        int indexMoved = 7;
        r.origin.y -= indexMoved;
        [[UIColor colorWithRed:59/255. green:73/255. blue:88/255. alpha:1] set];
        //set the image to whatever you want today's block to have
        [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tile-Border-Green.png"]] drawInRect:r];
        r.origin.y += indexMoved;
    }

    if ([marks count] > 0)
        [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:[[marks objectAtIndex:index] boolValue] font:font font2:font2];
    else
        [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:NO font:font font2:font2];
    index++;

}

//Finally, do blocks for the next month who's blocks are visible 
    //
    //

[[UIColor grayColor] set];
int i = 1;
while(index % 7 != 0){
    r = [self rectForCellAtIndex:index] ;


    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////

    int indexMoved = 7;
    r.origin.y -= indexMoved; //this moves the block to put it back in it's place

    //add an image to the rect - note you can add them over each other 
    [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"t.png"]] drawInRect:r];


    r.origin.y += indexMoved; //move back the block


    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////

    if ([marks count] > 0)
        [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:[[marks objectAtIndex:index] boolValue] font:font font2:font2];
    else
        [self drawTileInRect:r day:i mark:NO font:font font2:font2];
    i++;
    index++;


}
```

Notice that it's spilt into three main areas (each with a for loop). These are (in order) the blocks from the previous month that are still visible, the blocks from the current month and lastly the blocks from the coming month that are visible in the current view.

I really hope this helps someone because it took be a lot of headache to set up!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You may follow below steps to set custom image

1. **You have to right click the TapkuLibrary.bundle and select  show packet content**
2. **Now you can see folder as *Images* if you open that image folder you can see some folders**
3. **Among that folders you have to open the *calendar* folder**
4. **You can see so many images. now you can change images whatever you want**

I think it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the images in TapkuLibrary.bundle (right click, show packet content)